# Passing value after page load

Tags: angularjs

I have a timepicker and daypicker in my application. I need to pass these values to another object. However, the object returns undefined at page load since the time/date inputs are empty. So my question is how can I update the undefined value in the object once a time/date selection has been made..

code for time and date pickers:

```
        $scope.startTime = function () {
            $scope.time = $filter('date')($scope.time, 'HH:mm:ss');
            $rootScope.time = $scope.time;
            console.log($rootScope.time);
        }

        $scope.startDate = function() {
          $scope.dateStart = $filter('date')($scope.dateStart, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
          $rootScope.startDate = $scope.dateStart;
          console.log($rootScope.startDate);
        }

        $scope.endDate = function() {
          $scope.dateEnd = $filter('date')($scope.dateEnd, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
          $rootScope.endDate = $scope.dateEnd;
          console.log($rootScope.endDate);
        }

        $scope.selectedDay = function () {
         $rootScope.day = $scope.day;
         console.log($rootScope.day);

            }
```

the object which needs the updated values:

```
             $rootScope.schedule = {
              "@": {
              "let_run": "yes",
              "when_holiday": "ignore_holiday",
              // "begin":"06:30",
              "begin": $rootScope.time,
            },
              "weekdays": {

                 "day": {
                  "@": {
                    "day": $rootScope.day
                    // "day":"0"
                }
              }

              }
            };
            console.log($rootScope.schedule);
```

Comment: You need to update the actual object property itself. Assigning new value to the primitive `$rootScope.time` will not update anywhere you already used that variable

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is the problem - I am not sure how I can go about updating this object as it is only used as a parameter in a post method. Would $watcher or $apply be the route to  go?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to **resolve** this issue by updating the schedule object in each of the functions. for example:

```
$scope.startTime = function () {
            $scope.time = $filter('date')($scope.time, 'HH:mm:ss');
            $rootScope.time = $scope.time;
            $rootScope.schedule['@'].begin = $rootScope.time;
            console.log($rootScope.time);
        }
```